# Material UI - Change background color & other colors adjust?

Tags: material-ui

The example I'm working with is the Drawer element in material-ui@next

Is there a way to change the background color of the drawer and have the elements nested beneath (List ListItem) adjust their color, hover animations, etc. to fit this new color?

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond `background-color: inherit'`?

Comment: Yeah, probably something theme related.  What I've done so far is create a theme just to wrap this Drawer component.

Comment: @emp823 Do you want the `Drawer` theme to be different than the theme you're using for the rest of your app?